# What is an internal dimension/glue/muglue?

Tags: tex-core, syntax

In the documentation of `l3skip`'s `\dim_eval:n` one is warned

> This [...] requires suitable termination if used in a TeX-style assignment as it is not an ⟨*internal dimension*⟩.

Analogous warnings can be found in the descriptions for `\skip_eval:n` and `\muskip_eval:n` with ⟨*internal glue*⟩ and ⟨*internal muglue*⟩ in place of ⟨*internal dimension*⟩.

I am fairly familiar with handling skips and dimensions in TeX, but I have never before come across the expression *internal dimension*. In the TeXbook I could not find any explanation of the phrase outside of the rather technical grammar notation in chapter 24, which surely contains all the necessary information but did not really help me.

So, what exactly is an *internal dimension*? What are other types of dimensions? (External dimensions?) What are examples of different behavior of the two (like the one alluded to by the warning above)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll deal first with the general TeX concept, then why it's important in the documentation of those `expl3` functions.

An internal dimension (or internal count or whatever) is something which has been parsed by TeX and is now stored in the correct form. Thus TeX 'knows' that an internal dimension *is* a valid dimension, and does not have to 'look' for any further material. In contrast, an external dimension  (*etc.*) is something that is made up of discrete tokens and would have to be re-parsed by TeX to be used. Thus when we *write* `12.0pt`, we are giving an *external* representation (TeX would have to parse it to know it's a valid dimen), but after

```latex
\newdimen\mydimen
\mydimen=12pt %
```

I can use `\mydimen` and TeX does *not* need to parse anything: `\mydimen` holds an internal dimension.

Why is this important? It's all about TeX's parsing rules, in particular that TeX allows an optional trailing space after dimensions, integers, *etc.*, and more importantly that with an external representation, TeX doesn't stop parsing until it finds something that doesn't 'fit'. For example

```latex
\def\foo{123}
\newcount\fooint
\fooint=123 %
\newcount\testint
%%%
\testint=\foo 456 %
\showthe\testint
\testint=\fooint 456 %
\showthe\testint
```

you'll see that the first case gives the wrong result: we have a macro which simply expands to `123`, and TeX keeps looking for an integer until we hit the optional space. In contrast, with an internal count representation, there is no question of parsing: `\fooint` *is* `123`.

The key point is that an internal representation is 'safer' to use (plus faster): there's never a question of where it terminates.

---

How does this relate to `expl3`? Something like `\dim_eval:n` is used to take an expression and turn in into a dimension. However, it turns out to be convenient to allow that to also be just typeset, stored by expansion in a macro (`tl`), *etc.* To do that, we have to arrange that the evaluation results in an *external* representation, not an *internal* one. That means that these functions behave like storing a value as a macro: you have to watch the termination.

For all 'pure' `expl3` usage that's not an issue, as we have correct termination in the right places. But if you mix using these functions with more classical TeX programming, you need to know how they will behave. The [answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503871) shows this nicely.

---

For those who want the TeX details, `\dim_eval:n` is in primitive terms

```latex
\the\dimexpr #1\relax
```

while if we want to end up with an internal representation we only want

```latex
\dimexpr #1\relax
```

However, that can't be used in typesetting or (successfully) inside an `x`-type expansion, hence it's not suitable for the definition we want.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \dimeval \dim_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\mylen}

\begin{document}

Do an assignment \mylen=\dimeval{3pt+1cm} plus something else.

\end{document}
```

which raises an error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   s
l.12 ...assignment \mylen=\dimeval{3pt+1cm} plus s
                                                  omething else.
```

This is precisely what's referred to in `interface3`.

An `<internal dimension>` is any `\dimen` register or any internal register that stores a (rigid) length, such as `\parindent`; with e-TeX extensions, also `\dimexpr` is an instance of `<internal dimension>`.

Another important fact is that `\newlength` allocates a `\skip` register, so TeX will look forward for `plus` or `minus` specifications; this doesn't occur when `\setlength` is used, because the macro provides the suitable `\relax` termination.